# Check if variable holds File or Blob

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Javascript has both `File` and `Blob` for file representation, and both are almost the same thing. Is there a way to check if a variable is holding a `File` or a `Blob` type of data?

Comment: `if(x.name) ...` for quacks, `if(x.constructor===File)` for pedantics.

Comment: or  comapare the name of the constructoe `x.constructor.name == 'Blob'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

W3.org:

'A File object is a Blob object with a name attribute, which is a string;'

In case of File:

```
var d = new Date(2013, 12, 5, 16, 23, 45, 600);
var generatedFile = new File(["Rough Draft ...."], "Draft1.txt", {type: 'text/plain', lastModified: d});

console.log(typeof generatedFile.name == 'string'); // true
```

In case of Blob:

```
var blob = new Blob();
console.log(typeof blob.name); // undefined
```

Condition:

```
var isFile = typeof FileOrBlob.name == 'string';
```

Comment: What if can be a different object with name attribute?

Comment: We can do more detailed check on other attributes if we have another object having 'name' attribute, this is just a simple example.

Comment: What if the object can have most of attributes, but still it's not File or Blob object, I think this is buggy approach, it will return true if object has that properties but that object still may be not Blob or File. Why just not to test just like this `isFile instanceof File` ?

Comment: @Vendmant Any usage of the File constructor outside of typeOf will throw errors, testing for instance of File when File is not present does not work. I added:

typeof File !== 'undefined' && typeof file.name === 'string'

Which is not 100%, but gets a little more close to safety.

Answer (score 116):

Easiest way:

```
a = new File([1,2,3], "file.txt");
b = new Blob([1,2,3]);
c = "something else entirely";

a instanceof File
> true
b instanceof File
> false
c instanceof File
> false
```

Comment: File and Blob don't seem to be available globally in my nodejs environment. Do you know where we can import them from?

Answer (score 12):

One liner solution to make life easier.

*Based on Ric Flair*

```
const isFile = input => 'File' in window && input instanceof File;
const isBlob = input => 'Blob' in window && input instanceof Blob;

const a = new File([1,2,3], "foo.txt", {type: "text/plain"});
...

console.log(isFile(a)) // true
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on Nick Brunt's:

```
function isFile(input) {
   if ('File' in window && input instanceof File)
      return true;
   else return false;
}

function isBlob(input) {
    if ('Blob' in window && input instanceof Blob)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

//Test
const a = new File([1,2,3], "foo.txt", {type: "text/plain"});
const b = new Blob([1,2,3]);
const c = "something else entirely";

console.log(isFile(a));    //true
console.log(isBlob(a));    //true
console.log(isFile(b));    //false
console.log(isBlob(b));    //true
console.log(isFile(c));    //false
console.log(isBlob(c));    //false
```

Won't work for Opera mini as well as IE. Though with IE it won't matter because you may only use file input tags, in that case you'll definitely know it's a file.

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 4):

Compare the constructor class:

```
var b = new Blob()
console.log(b.constructor === Blob) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me when trying to determine is an object is a file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

if(file.type){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

If I want to check if it is a specific file type like an image I do this:

```
if(file.type && file.type.indexOf('image') !== -1){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```